# Is unconditional love of God biblical?

Tags: 1-john

1 John 4:9–10
“In this the love of God was made manifest among us, that God sent his only son into the world, so that we might live through him. In this is love, not that we have loved God but that he loved us and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our sins.”

Does God love everyone?

Malachi 1:3 but Esau I have hated

Comment: Your question appears to to be based on the assumption that ‘hate’ is the opposite of ‘love’, which [biblically] it isn’t, and can’t be substantiated. Whereas God loving man unconditionally can. (John 3:16)

Comment: @Dave, The condition in John 3:16 is whosoever believes.

Answer (score 2):

The best definition of agape love is, “God so loved … that He gave His son …” (John 3:16).  The “agape” love is the central most important characteristic, the very essence, of God (1 John 4:8, 16).  Love’s outward manifestation is grace.  It is God as love that defines God and all else about Him such as justice/righteousness tempered with kindness.

This principled love of God (1 John 4:8, 16) is to be imitated by all Christians (John 13:34, 35) and is motivated by God’s love for us (1 John 4:9, 10, 19-21, 2 Cor 5:14).  Thus, love is quintessentially Christian and reached its zenith when God gave Jesus as the solution to the sin problem (2 Cor 5:14, Eph 2:4, 3:19, 5:2, John 3:16).  Therefore, Christians should have as their primary focus their love of, and love to God (Matt 22:37, Deut 6:5), and secondarily love to fellow humans (Matt 22:39, Lev 19:18).

Back to the OP's question, which can essentially be boiled down to, How extensive is this love of God?  It is answered in the same letter of John 2:2 -

> He [Christ] is the propitiation for our [believing Christians] sins,
> and not for ours only but also for the sins of the whole world.

Thus, Christ does love all people everywhere.  There is much evidence of this:

- John 12:32, “I [Jesus] … will draw all people to myself.”
- Rom 3:23, 24, “… for all have sinned … and all are freely forgiven...”
- Rom 5:8, 10, “… while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. … if, while were God’s enemies, we were reconciled to him by the death of His Son, …”
- Rom 5:18, “Therefore, as through one man’s offense judgment came to all people, resulting in condemnation, even so through one Man’s righteous act the free gift came to all people, resulting in justification of life.”
- 2 Cor 5:14, “…we are convinced that one died for all, and therefore all died.”
- 2 Cor 5:18, 19, “…God was reconciling the world to Himself in Christ …”
- 1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
- 1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”

So, what are we to make of texts like Mal 1:2, 3, "“I have loved you,” says the LORD.  But you ask, “How have You loved us?”  “Was not Esau Jacob’s brother?” declares the LORD. “Yet Jacob I have loved, **but Esau I have hated**, and I have made his mountains a wasteland and left his inheritance to the desert jackals.”

Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary observes:

> hated—not positively, but relatively; that is, did not choose him out
> to be the object of gratuitous favor, as I did Jacob (compare Lu
> 14:26, with Mt 10:37; Ge 29:30, 31; De 21:15, 16).

The pulpit commentary is more helpful still:

> And I hated Esau. St. Paul quotes these words (Romans 9:13) in order
> to illustrate his position, "that the purpose of God according to
> election might stand, not of works, but of him that calleth." Even
> before his birth Jacob was the chosen one, and Esau, the elder, was to
> serve the younger. This mystery of Divine election has seemed to some
> to be stated so harshly that they have thought that the words of the
> text need to be softened, or to be modified by their explanation. Thus
> they give the glosses, "I have preferred Jacob to Esau;" "I have loved
> Esau less than Jacob;" or they have limited the terms "love" end
> "hatred" to the bestowing or withholding of temporal blessings; or
> they have affirmed that Esau was hated because God foresaw his
> unworthiness, and Jacob was beloved owing to his foreseen piety and
> faithfulness. The whole question is discussed by Augustine, 'De Div.
> Quint. ad Simplic.,' 1:18 (11:433). ... But Malachi is not speaking of
> the predestination of the one brother and the reprobation of the
> other; he is contrasting the histories of the two peoples represented
> by them; as Jerome puts it, "In Jacob vos dilexi, in Esau Idumaeos
> odio habui." Both nations sinned; both are punished; but Israel by
> God's free mercy was forgiven and restored, while Edom was left in the
> misery which it had brought upon itself by its own iniquity.

We must also recall that Jesus, despite his well-known saying in John 13:34, 35 actually advised his followers to hate some people:

> Luke 14:26 - "If anyone comes to me and does not hate father and
> mother, wife and children, brothers and sisters--yes, even their own
> life--such a person cannot be my disciple.

This cannot be construed to mean that we must hate our close relatives but simply that our love for them must be greatly exceeded by our love to Jesus and God.  Thus, in Biblical terms, "hate" is a relative term.